# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html2text'

Tags: python, package, odoo

I am runnig a python based application (Odoo) on Ubuntu Server, it is throwing this error in the backend server logs. Some sites suggested to install the missing packages/library `html2text`.

I have installed that too by running
`pip3 install html2text`

and verified it by
`pip3 show html2text`

which shows location of site-packages of python
`Location: /home/dell/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.

However, the system is still throwing this mentioned error in the logs `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html2text' - - -`.

Is there anything I am missing related to **path** or **installation steps**?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. The problem was with default python package path installation. Since my application was looking for python packages at this location `/usr/lib/python/dist-packages` and the package `html2text` was installed in `/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

I had to install the `html2text` package in `/usr/lib/python/dist-packages` by running

`sudo pip3 install --target=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages html2text`